# "export: `=': not a valid identifier" when exporting variables

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to read a file and for each line, turn the second argument into a variable, and store the first argument in that varaible.

I have this code:

```
while read i  
do  
 V1=$(echo $i |awk '{print $2}')  
 V2=$(echo $i |awk '{print $1}')  
export $V1=$V2  
done < test  

echo $a  
echo $b  
echo $c
```

while it works, it gives me the error:
"export: `=': not a valid identifier"
 If I remove the $ from the export line, then the code does not function ( a,b,c have no values)

How can I make it work, without the error? (I do need the a,b,c variables with their values later)
These are the file contents:
10 a
20 b
60 c

Comment: You don’t need all that `awk` stuff; `read` can do the splitting for you, e.g. `while read -r v k ; do export "$k=$v" ; done < test`

Comment: As for the error: Could it be that the file contains empty lines? Run the script with `bash -x` (or add `set -x` near the top) to see what is going on.

Comment: (OT: May I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net ? It will show you a couple of potential issues with your code.)

Comment: Thanks @Biffen, apparently there was an empty line after the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you echo V1 and V2 individually after assignment and check if there is any space character saved in them ?

"export: `=': not a valid identifier"
 generally comes when the shell tries to interpret that as a request to export three names: 10, = and a. = isn't a valid variable name, so the command fails.

Comment: Or when `$V1` and `$V2` are empty and the command gets expanded as `export =`

Comment: Apparently there was an issue in the input file. There was an empty line after the last one. When I cleared that the error disappeared.